# Evaluating multiple files from a folder using opa eval command

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

I have seen this on the OPA website that I could use the following:

To Evaluate a policy on the command line.
**./opa eval -i input.json -d example.rego**

In my case, I have multiple input files and I have modified it to

**./opa eval -i /tmp/tfplan.json -d /tmp/example.rego -d /tmp/input1.json -d /tmp/input2.json**

Rather than specifying the files as input1, input2 and so on individually, can I directly modify it to read all the json files present in the tmp folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! The CLI will accept directories for the `-d`/`--data` and `-b`/`--bundle` parameters and recursively load files from them.

Ex with:

```
/tmp/foo/input1.json
/tmp/foo/input2.json
```

`opa eval -d /tmp/foo/input1.json -d /tmp/foo/input2.json ..`

Is the same as

`opa eval -d /tmp/foo ..`

Keep in mind that `-d`/`--data` will attempt to load *ANY* files found in the directory, which can sometimes lead to conflicts (eg, duplicate keys in the data document) or loading incorrect files. So be careful about pointing at `/tmp` as its likely to include additional files you didn't neccisarily want (note the example above used a sub-directory). Typically we recommend using `-b`/`--bundle` and providing files as `data.json` with a directory structure following the bundle spec https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/management/#bundle-file-format which can help avoid most of those common problems.